# How to create custom button view that can accept corner radius and color dynamically and change accordingly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-custom-view

How to create custom button view that can accept corner radius and background color dynamically rather than making shape file for every button. 
I know that i can extend to the Button class and also create attribute set to accept the values, but just dont know how to change corner radius of the button.

Comment: If you just want do add corner radius and background why don't you use `CardView`?

Comment: No, i want button, and my own custom button, so that i can use it everywhere, so that i dont have to create shape file for every new button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`MaterialButton`**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btnWithdraw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="@string/withdraw"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorLightRed"
    app:cornerRadius="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtAgentPin" />
```

To change background color use this

```
btnWithdraw.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE)
```

To change cornerRadius use this

```
rootView.btnWithdraw.cornerRadius = 20
```

**NOTE :** make sure you have added below `dependencies` in your `Build.Gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a xml file in your drawable folder like mybutton.xml and paste the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
        </shape>
    </item>  
    <item >
       <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
       </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

here button code below

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Buttons" />
```

Comment: I said i dont want to use shape everytime i create a button, i want to eradicate that dependency. I want to create a custom view so that i can use it everytime rather than creating shape xml for every button.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 val shape = GradientDrawable()
shape.cornerRadius = 18f

// add some color
// You can add your random color generator here
// and set color
shape.setColor(Color.RED);
// now find your view and add background to it
view.btn.background = shape
```

Comment: Is it useful? revert back if you have any query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CardView` to create custom button with corner radius and color dynamically.

XML Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Change Color dynamically :

```
CardView main_card=findViewById(R.id.main_card);
main_card.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("Submit");
    final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
      btn.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.ready) );
    } else {
      btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready));
    }
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
    LayoutParams buttonlayout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.addView(btn, buttonlayout);
```

add drwaable R.drawable.library_cirecle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/outerRectangle">
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="#FCD366" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Change color in code

```
Drawable tempDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.library_cirecle);
LayerDrawable bubble = (LayerDrawable) tempDrawable; (cast to root element in xml)
GradientDrawable solidColor = (GradientDrawable) bubble.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.outerRectangle);
solidColor.setColor(colorToPaint);
imageView.setImageDrawable(tempDrawable);
```